# Apache Beam BigqueryIO.Write getSuccessfulInserts not working

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are creating a simple apache beam pipeline which inserts data into a bigquery table and We are trying to get the tableRows which have been successfully Inserted into the table and tableRows which are errored, the code is as shown in the screenshot

[image: Pipeline code]

According to the following documentation:
https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.33.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/WriteResult.html
`BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()` returns a `WriteResult` object which has `getSuccessfulInserts()` which will return a `PCollection<TableRow>` which contains the `TableRows` that have been successfully inserted and `getFailedInserts()` will return another `PCollection<TableRow>` which contains the `TableRows` that have been failed.

But when we are testing the pipeline `getFailedInserts()` seems to be working, it is getting the `TableRows` which are failed, but `getSuccessfulInserts()` is always getting an empty `PCollection` we have tried everything but it doesn't seem to work. Are we missing something here?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi Haresh, this may be a silly request, but can you make sure that the both project and table name are correct. In addition, can you try adding ".withExtendedErrorInfo()" to the writeTableRows() transform.

Comment: @Cubez The rows are getting inserted into the bigquery, the project and table name are correct but for updating the audit info, we will be needing no. of records inserted successfully, for that we are trying to use getSuccessfulInserts function but that is returning an empty PCollection instead that is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in the Apache Beam 2.36.0 release following some refactoring. The fix is in https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/16768 and will be in the 2.37.0 release.

Comment: yes @Cubez thanks a lot for the fix, what might be the planned release date for this any idea ?

Comment: Does that mean the Apache beam 2.35.0 version is it working ?

Comment: Actually we were using 2.35.0, where it is not working, i tried in 2.34.0 also it is still now working

Comment: Hi Haresh, sorry to hear that the feature doesn't work on earlier versions. I'll let the team know of the updated impact. Apache Beam aims to release about every 5 weeks (plus or minus one). So the 2.37.0 release should be out around mid to late March (this date isn't final). Feel free to email us at user@beam.apache.org for more info.